# How to update token when the user logs in in express js?

Tags: node.js, express, collections, token, express-jwt

I want to update token in user collection when the user logs in. So far, I have tried this.

```
router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  User.find({ email: req.body.email })
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
      if (user.length < 1) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          message: "Auth failed"
        });
      }
      bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0].password, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(401).json({
            message: "Auth failed"
          });
        }
        if (result) {
          const token2 = jwt.sign(
            {
              email: user[0].email,iat: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) - 30
            },
            "123",
            {
                expiresIn: "1h"
            }
          );
          User.update({token : token2 })
            .exec()

          return res.status(200).json({
            message: "Auth successful",
            token: token2
          });
        }
        res.status(401).json({
          message: "Auth failed"
        });
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});
```

here new token is getting generated but it is not being saved in the user collection. I want to update new token in the collection.

Can anyone know where I am missing?

Comment: May I know your `MongoDB` version?

Comment: I think your update is happening before execution of `jwt.sign`. See if you can get any callback for `jwt.sign`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Something like:

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try{
    const user = await User.find({ email: req.body.email });
    if (user.length < 1) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        message: "Auth failed"
      });
    }
    bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0].password, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          message: "Auth failed"
        });
      }
      if (result) {
        const token2 = jwt.sign(
          {
            email: user[0].email,iat: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) - 30
          },
          "123",
          {
            expiresIn: "1h"
          }
        );
        User.update({_id:user[0]._id},{$set:{token : token2 }},{new: true});

        return res.status(200).json({
          message: "Auth successful",
          token: token2
        });
      }
      res.status(401).json({
        message: "Auth failed"
      });
    });
  }
  catch(err){
    res.status(500).json({
      error: err
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: remove .exec() from find also because when using then we do not require .exec() to execute the query it will be executed.

Comment: Then you have to run the update query outside of the then used for find.Its better use async with await.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
      jwt.sign(
        {
          email: user[0].email,iat: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) - 30
        },
        "123",
        {
            expiresIn: "1h"
        }, function(err, token2) {
           User.update({token : token2 }).exec() //Change the query to update

         return res.status(200).json({
            message: "Auth successful",
            token: token2
         });
       }
      );
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: now token is not getting print only auth successful is printed

Comment: can you put a console and check the value of token2? @BhaktiThakkar

Answer (score 0):

Firstly understand why do you need to refresh the token. Once you create the token you can store that token as a session variable in a web, internal storage of your mobile etc...

Instead of refresh of token you can create another token. 
In another way you can set timeout for the token. Token will be invalid after  that time period.